# Snort network instruction Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, security

I'm trying to learn network intrusion detection.  When I try to launch [Snort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort_%28software%29), in [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) mode, I get this message (I'm running [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X)):

```
Initializing Network Interface en1
ERROR: OpenPcap() FSM compilation failed: 
    syntax error
PCAP command: snort
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Make sure you are running Snort
   as root (or a user with permissions to
   drop into promiscuous mode.)
2. Make sure your configuration is valid.
   (`snort -t -c snort.conf` I believe.)
3. If all else fails ask on the
   forums at snort.org.  They're
   helpful.